# Dijkstra shortest path algorithm error

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

I wrote the following code to implement the Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <cstring>

int findPath(std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int>>> graph, int x, int y) {
    int n = graph.size();
    std::priority_queue < std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>, std::greater<std::pair<int, int>>> pq;
    pq.push(std::pair<int, int>(0, x));
    int *visited = new int[n + 1]{};
    int *distance = new int[n + 1];
    memset(distance, -1, sizeof(*distance) * (n + 1));
    distance[x] = 0;

    int current;
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        current = pq.top().second;
        pq.pop();
        if (current == y) {
            return distance[y];
        }
        if (!visited[current]) {
            visited[current] = 1;
            for (std::list<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator it = graph[current].begin(); it != graph[current].end(); it++) {
                if (!visited[it->first]) {
                    if (distance[it->first] == -1 || distance[it->first] > distance[current] + it->second) {
                        distance[it->first] = distance[current] + it->second;
                        pq.push(std::pair<int, int>(distance[it->first], it->first));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return distance[y];
}

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int n;
    int m;
    int x;
    int y;

    std::cin >> n >> m >> x >> y;

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int>>> graph(n + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
        graph[a].push_back(std::pair<int, int>(b, c));
    }

    std::cout << findPath(graph, x, y) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The input is N - number of vertexes, M - number of edges, x, y - 2 vertexes.
Then you have M lines of a, b, c which implies that you have a path from a to b with distance c.

Also you can have multiple edges from one vertex to another.

The goal is to find the shortest path from x to y. (-1 if there is no path)
I am using a priority queue of pairs (first one is the current distance to the vertex, and the second is the vertex).

The code works for some tests and gives a wrong answer for the rest (its from a judge system, so I can't see what the tests are).

I looked at it for an hour and I can't seem to find why it is not working.

I would be grateful if you can find the mistake, and why is it not working.

A sample input:

5 5 1 5

1 2 1

1 3 2

2 4 4

3 4 4

4 5 5

Output:
10

EDIT: There seems to be no error in the code. The task was ambiguous in the way that if there is a path from a to b, there is one from b to a. That was the error.

Comment: It would be nice to have a verifiable example. Do you have the option to write your own tests? What does a test look like?

Comment: Added an edit with a sample input/output

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki The visited is set to the vertexes that are popped out of the queue i.e. the ones to which I already know the min distance. And I am not updating the priority queue, I am just adding a new vertex with less distance (it should be before the old one, and when the queue reaches the the vertex a second time, it will be visited, so no problem)

Comment: What kind of test is a "shro" test?

Comment: @nbro Oh sorry I guess that mistake is so big you can't tell what it is right? And there is no mention of a "shro" or "short" TEST :)

Comment: @Poyr23 I was joking :)